# Grab old inputs in components

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have a blade file that contains only one component

```
<div>
    <select-exercise></select-exercise>
</div>
```

And, the template of the component is like this

selectExercise.vue

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <select class="selectpicker form-control"  v-model="customizedExercise.sets_duration"  name="sets_duration[]" id ="sets_duration"> 
            <option v-for="number in numbers" value="{{number}}">{{number}}</option> 
        </select> 
    </span>

    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <select class="selectpicker form-control"  v-model="customizedExercise.reps"  name="reps[]" id="reps"> 
            <option v-for="number in numbers" value="{{number}}">{{number}}</option> 
        </select> 
    </span>
</div>
```

How do you grab an old input and show them, in case a user failed to pass a form validation and redirect back?

I tried

```
<div>
    <select-exercise :input="{{old('key')}}"></select-exercise>
</div>
```

But,it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can set old value by old('key') if value is already set it will be set $key

```
value="{{ old('key', $key) }}">
```

Comment: Thanks.But,you cannot use a php function on .vue extension file right??